# Find $\int\frac{1}{\sin\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Find the integral:
>   $$
> I=\int\frac{1}{\sin\sqrt{x}}dx
> $$

Well, here is what I've done so far:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{x}=t\Rightarrow dt=\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}},\ \ dx=2tdt\\
&I=2\int\frac{t}{\sin t}dt=\ ?
\end{aligned}
$$
The problem is to calculate the last integral. $t$ in the numerator makes it rather insolvable.

Comment: I don't think that the is a closed form... why do you think that you can compute it ?

Comment: I don't think it has a closed form.

Comment: Well, I've been given this integral as an extra problem in the class.

Comment: Is the denominator $\sin^2 \sqrt x$, by any chance?

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Recall that $$\sin\theta = \frac{\exp(\mathrm i\theta) - \exp(-\mathrm i\theta)}{2\mathrm i}$$

Therefore,
$$\int\frac t{\sin t}\,\mathrm dt = \int\frac{2\mathrm it}{\exp(\mathrm it) - \exp(-\mathrm it)}\,\mathrm dt = 2\mathrm i\int\frac{t\exp(\mathrm it)}{\exp(\mathrm 2\mathrm it)-1}\,\mathrm dt$$

Let $u = \mathrm it\implies\mathrm dt = -\mathrm i\mathrm du$.

$$2\int\frac{\mathrm it\exp(\mathrm it)}{\exp(\mathrm 2\mathrm it)-1}\,\mathrm dt\equiv -2\int\frac{u\exp(u)}{\exp(2u) - 1}\,\mathrm du$$

Let $v = \exp(u)\implies \mathrm du = \exp(-u)\mathrm dv$. Then, $u = \ln(v)$ and $\exp(2u) = v^2$.

$$\int\frac{u\exp(u)}{\exp(2u) - 1}\,\mathrm du\equiv\int\frac{\ln(v)}{v^2 - 1}\,\mathrm dv$$

Comment: And then I have $...=-2i\int\frac{mdm}{e^m-e^{-m}},\ m=it$. Not much better :(

Comment: See my edit to the answer. I think it's pretty straightforward from here. Linearity and another substitution should get you an answer with dilogarithms $(L_2)$ in it.

Comment: You lost $i$ term in the next to last line of your solution.

Comment: We get rid of the $\mathrm i$ because $\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt} = \mathrm i \implies \mathrm dt = -\mathrm i\mathrm du$.

Comment: Yes, but you made a substitution in the numerator ($it=u$). Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Notice that I originally had the $\mathrm i$ term outside. Does the edit make it better?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @an4s's answer $$\int\frac{\log(v)}{v^2 - 1}\, dv=\frac 12 \left(\int\frac{\log(v)}{v - 1}\, dv -\int\frac{\log(v)}{v + 1}\, dv\right)$$ and one integration by parts leads to 
$$\int\frac{\log(v)}{v + a}\, dv=\log (v) \log \left(1+\frac{v}{a}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{v}{a}\right)$$ So, for $a=1$
$$\int\frac{\log(v)}{v^2 - 1}\, dv=\frac 12\Big(\text{Li}_2(v)-\text{Li}_2(-v) \Big)-\log (v) \tanh
   ^{-1}(v)$$